# undefined method `update_attributes' for nil:NilClass when updating object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm receiving the error "undefined method `update_attributes' for nil:NilClass" when I try to update my page object. I confirmed in pry that @page is empty, but I can't figure out why?

```
def new
    @page = Page.new
    @subjects = Subject.order('position ASC')
    @page_count = Page.count + 1
  end

  def create
    @page = Page.new(page_params)
    if @page.save
      flash[:notice] = 'New page added!'
      redirect_to action: 'index'
    else
      @subjects = Subject.order('position ASC')
      @page_count = Page.count + 1
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @page = Page.find_by(id: params[:id])
    @subjects = Subject.order('position ASC')
    @page_count = Page.count
  end

  def update
    @page = Page.find_by(id: params[:id])
    if @page.update_attributes(page_params)
      flash[:notice] = 'Page has been updated!'
      redirect_to action: 'show', id: @page.id
    else
      @subjects = Subject.order('position ASC')
      @page_count = Page.count
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
     private

  def page_params
    params.require(:page).permit(:subject_id, :name, :permalink, :position, :visible)
  end

Routes:
match ':controller(/:action(/:id))', :via => [:get, :post]
```

Comment: check the output of `Page.find_by(id: params[:id])` in your console.

Comment: The console is displaying this error:
`ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: page):
  app/controllers/pages_controller.rb:62:in `page_params'
  app/controllers/pages_controller.rb:39:in `update'`


I guess it's throwing this error, because I'm using params.require(:page) with my strong parameters but there's no object coming through? I'm sorry, I'm fairly new to Rails.

Comment: ok.. check then `puts params` in the console... or in browser *network* tab.

Comment: No 'id' coming through...
`=> {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"eZy9jQd9MYterxH43Pkfquh91dk/qux0dCB7c6apE2c=",
 "page"=>
  {"subject_id"=>"24",
   "name"=>"Testing Page",
   "permalink"=>"0",
   "position"=>"1",
   "visible"=>"1"},
 "commit"=>"Update page",
 "controller"=>"pages",
 "action"=>"update"}`

Comment: I can't see any `:id` in your param hash.

Comment: Yes, there's no 'id' coming through.. that's my problem. I'm just not sure why?

Comment: Just do `rails s`.. then do click on `edit` action. Check in the `console`, if you are getting the `:id` value or not..

Comment: Yes, 'id' is appearing:
`Processing by PagesController#edit as */*
  Parameters: {"id"=>"22"}`

I'm so confused why it's not coming through when the create action is processed.

Comment: You won't have an "id" in a create action - id is only passed in when the action is happening to a persisted record.

Comment: Oops, yes, I meant the id is not coming through in my 'update' action.

Comment: Please share your view: `edit.html.erb`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that `params[:id]` isn't blank, you can check your views for it. Then you can use search by id, and in case of no record use `Object`'s `#try` method:

```
@page = Page.find_by_id(params[:id])
if @page.try(:update_attributes, page_params)
...
```

Comment: The problem is that params[:id] is blank when the 'create' action is called. However, in the 'new' action params[:id] is present. I'm confused as to why this is happening.

I tried your code, and am receiving a new error:
`undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass`
I guess it's basically telling me the same thing - params[:id] is blank.

My apologies in advance as I'm new to Rails.

Comment: @user3403328 verify your views, if new action contains id, however it shell not. show in post your new/show views

Comment: Wow, you're right. The problem was in my views. My god, valuable lesson learned that I need to double check everywhere. Thanks for that!